# Trying to transform XMl to XML using XSL with C# Console App

Tags: c#, xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file - for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StudentHistory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Item>
        <Week>1988-05-12</Week>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Counsel>1</Counsel>
        <Completed>1</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Week>1988-05-12</Week>
        <Name>AA</Name>
        <Counsel>2</Counsel>
        <Completed>1</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Week>1988-05-13</Week>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Counsel>2</Counsel>
        <Completed>1</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Week>1988-05-14</Week>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Counsel>3</Counsel>
        <Completed>1</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Week>1988-05-15</Week>
        <Name>D</Name>
        <Counsel>4</Counsel>
        <Completed>1</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Week>1988-05-16</Week>
        <Name>E</Name>
        <Counsel>5</Counsel>
        <Completed>1</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Week>1988-05-17</Week>
        <Name>F</Name>
        <Counsel>6</Counsel>
        <Completed>1</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Week>1988-05-18</Week>
        <Name>G</Name>
        <Counsel>7</Counsel>
        <Completed>0</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Week>2018-01-16</Week>
        <Name>H</Name>
        <Counsel>-1</Counsel>
        <Completed>1</Completed>
        <Description>XX</Description>
    </Item>
</StudentHistory>
```

In the final file I will have many entries with the same "Week". So I followed a tutorial and am just testing at this stage. I came up with this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="items-by-week" match="Item" use="Week" />
  <xsl:template match="StudentHistory/Item">
    <xsl:for-each select="Item[count(. | key('items-by-week', Week)[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:sort select="Week" />
      <xsl:value-of select="Week" />
      <xsl:for-each select="key('items-by-week', Week)">
        <xsl:sort select="Name" />
        <xsl:value-of select="Name" /> (<xsl:value-of select="Counsel" />)
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I wrote a C# console application that does this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            myXslTrans.Load(@"d:\TestTransform2.xsl");
            myXslTrans.Transform(@"d:\Test-Students2.xml", @"d:\Test-Students2-Final.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it my output xml is empty. What have I overlooked? It should have written something out with the names grouped by week.

Comment: Ok.  Where is you XMI that you are starting with?  You have an xml and a xsd schema.  I'm totally confused.

Comment: I am taking the first xml with the XSL to make a new xml. Eventually the new xml will have some othe stuff in it. I just wanted to try to get it working first. I am starting with the xml listed. Processing it with the XSL. I need to end up you see with a xml that has all items grouped in a dare node but I not got that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is real simple using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<Student> students = doc.Descendants(ns + "Item").Select(x => new Student() {
                week = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "Week"),
                name = (string)x.Element(ns + "Name"),
                counsel = (int)x.Element(ns + "Counsel"),
                completed = (int)x.Element(ns + "Completed") == 1 ? true : false,
                description = (string)x.Element(ns + "Description")
            }).ToList();

            var weeks = students.GroupBy(x => x.week).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public DateTime week { get; set;}
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int counsel { get; set; }
        public Boolean completed { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are basically suggesting that I don’t try to do a transform but programmatically read the XML and write a new. Yes that is simple. 

Comment: At least for the reading.  You can't tag the same class for reading and writing if the XML formats are different between read and write.